# jhipster application load very slow with production

Tags: angular5, jhipster

use

```
yarn webpack:prod
```

to build a package for production. when deploy to the cloud (the bandwidth is 1M bit per second).

It tooks me about 30 seconds to load all assets, I know the bandwidth may a bit of poor, aside of that, I want to know how to improve the load speed, aot is one option (another is lazy loading, this will be done with source code level), how to apply aot in this case?

Comment: You can see exactly what is taking up space in your bundle by looking at the `stats.html` file under your build directory after a prod build.  JHipster already applies AOT in production https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/752e01fe2d46d34ee622b6f5bbf420eec3b3ed8d/webpack/webpack.prod.js#L104

Comment: @Jon thanks, found the size of stats.html is huge, 25704 KB, cannot navigate smoothly inside such file with notepad++.

Comment: You should open it in the browser, not in notepad.  It visualizes your project dependencies as seen in the readme here https://github.com/chrisbateman/webpack-visualizer  Without more information like if you added any dependencies, it's hard to guess why it takes so long

Comment: @JonRuddell looks amazing, I will investigate it, a lot of node_modules(68.4%).

Comment: @JonRuddell angular size is 1.6M, is it possible to reduce further?